# How can I use firebase functions efficiently?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Functions for the mobile project. I have never used firebase functions for other projects. I want to learn to efficiently usage. Please write to me with your suggestions and mistakes. 
My code in index.js;

```js
const load = () => {
 ....
}

const soapValidate = () => {
 ....
}

const loginParse = () => {
 ....
}

const loginValidate = () => {
 ....
}

const roomValidate = () => {
 ....
}

const roomParse = () => {
 ....
}


exports.remoteLogin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}


exports.setRoom = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}
```

The above functions receive and process data from the remote server. There will be many similar functions. Does it make sense to put them all in an index.js file? Is it logical to separate functionally into different files?

Answer (score 0):

### In case of using typescript

I'm using typescript usually.

index.ts

```
import { remoteLogin } from "./login";
import { setRoom } from "./room";


export {
  remoteLogin,
  setRoom
}
```

login.ts

```
export const remoteLogin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}
```

room.ts

```
export const setRoom = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}
```

### In case of using javascript

index.js

```
const login = require("./login");
const room = require("./room");

exports.remoteLogin = login.remoteLogin
exports.setRoom = room.setRoom
```

login.js

```
exports.remoteLogin = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}
```

room.js

```
exports.setRoom = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. Looks nice in the development process, but does it make a difference performance on the firebase side?